# Spring Integration create new session if sftp is not active without closing them

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

i work on a project which uses Spring Integration to connect to multiple SFTP Servers.

To establish the connection and getting the wanted files the following code gets used:

```
<!-- Session factory for new SSH sessions for the server of *this* context -->
<bean id="sftpFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="${sftp.remote.host}" />
    <property name="port" value="${sftp.remote.port}" />
    <property name="user" value="${sftp.remote.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${sftp.remote.password}" />
    <property name="privateKey"
        value="${sftp.remote.privatekey.path}"></property>
    <property name="privateKeyPassphrase"
        value="${sftp.remote.privatekey.passphrase}"></property>
</bean>

    <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInboundAdapter"
    session-factory="sftpFactory" remote-directory="${sftp.remote.directory}"
    charset="UTF-8"
    local-directory="file:${sftp.local.directory}/${sftp.remote.host}_${sftp.remote.port}"
    auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="${sftp.remote.deleteSourceFiles}"
    channel="channelDelayAfterSftpDownload" filename-pattern="*.xml" local-filename-generator-expression="#this + '.' + T(class.to.generate.filename).createRandomUuid()">
    <si:poller fixed-rate="${sftp.remote.pollerRate}" time-unit="MILLISECONDS"
        max-messages-per-poll="100" />
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The code works fine if everything is configured correct.

My problem is the following:
If a connection to the SSH Server is established but SFTP is not enabled on the Server, a new session is created for every poll. But the connections don't get closed which finally prevent the server from working.

The Exception that gets thrown when trying to connect is:

```
ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:170)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:83)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:143)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.receive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:146)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:111)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java:67)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:144)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:236)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:49)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:231)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:53)
at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:266)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:55)
at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:53)
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:180)
at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:160)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:204)
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:262)
... 26 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:507)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:158)
at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:196)
... 27 more
```

Is there a property i have to set or am i just missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using?

Comment: We use Spring Integration version: 2.2.4.RELEASE and Spring version: 3.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: I reached out the jsch folks and they have provided a fix - can you check it out? https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-3305?focusedCommentId=99180&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-99180

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I will take a look at it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following Jira for reference:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-1921

Thus, if you upgrade to the latest Snapshot release, your issue should go away.

Furthermore, there are several other easy workarounds available for the existing 2.0.4 release to solve your issue. In my opinion the best solution would be to explicitly specify the "remote-file-separator" attribute on the "int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter" element, such as:

remote-file-separator="/"

Alternatively, as long as you ensure that the "remote-directory" has a trailing path separator you should be fine as well (e.g. remote-directory="/poll/")

Please let us know if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the JSch client to me (he doesn't close the socket if `session.connect()` fails); but we can add a workaround to call `disconnect()` even if `connect()` fails.

Feel free to open a JIRA issue [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT).

Comment: I reached out the jsch folks and they have provided a fix - can you check it out? https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-3305?focusedCommentId=99180&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-99180